# Chart.js color is not getting changed

Tags: html, css, chart.js

i am trying to use chart js to create a dashboard. i am trying to being with a the example given their getting started page. but color of the bars are always gray. i know i am missing something very trivial  but i cannot figure out what. any help will be hugely appreciated

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Chart.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //var ctx = $("#myChart");
            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `backgroundColor` to your dataset to change the color of all bars.

```
...
backgroundColor: 'rgba(121, 121, 255, 0.2)',
...
```

If you pass it an array of colors, it will set the color bar by bar for the dataset

```
...
backgroundColor: ['rgba(121, 121, 255, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 121, 121, 0.2)',... ],
...
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/L9qsb3h4/
Fiddle (bar by bar) - http://jsfiddle.net/0b98k2g8/